# Flag rejected as moderator cannot do it

Tags: discussion

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988158/take-the-address-of-a-one-past-the-end-array-element-via-subscript-legal-by-the) I think it should be split into two questions because it is significantly different in C than in C++, and there is a significant volume of discussion. This would require migrating the answers pertaining to C onto a new question.

I flagged to see if a moderator would consider this and the flag was rejected with " declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"

What is the correct way to proceed?

Comment: Moderators can't "split" a question or "move answers around". I believe only developers can do that - and only under rare circumstances.

Comment: @Mysticial OK. I have seen it done before (with it saying "this answer has been moved from {other question}") or similar

Comment: That's for merging. Moderators can merge, which combines answers together from two different questions. But they can't arbitrarily move an answer from question A to question B.

Answer (score 3):

Moderators don't have the ability to move an answer from one question to another, that's something that only a developer can do, and not something that we'd normally do. In the year + that I've had that level of access, I have yet to use the feature. In fact, I can't remember the last time someone did, I'm not sure if it even works anymore. It's there if some kind of bug ends up putting an answer on the wrong question, which (a *long* time ago) happened occasionally.

This larger concern is an unfortunate and *constant* pain when it comes to the C and C++ tags. I *do not* know much about C++, yet I have a tag badge for it, just to give you an indicator.

Both communities try very hard to nip a question being derailed with the presence of a tag that doesn't really apply as much as possible. A lot of new users use both tags, because they're not quite sure which one to use, or just want a larger audience since an appreciable number of C++ programmers are quite competent with C as well. We fix that by removing the errant tag, and that *generally* avoids the entire Library of Congress from being written and re-hashed in comments.

But there are some questions where you simply can't keep the two separated, and ... this is one of those cases. You'll find answers there that are quite good depending on your application and need, and that's okay. There's not a lot of net gain to be found by separating them, and someone working with both would appreciate the context that both sides lend.

And, well, part of the question was speaking to *why* it might be different, if in fact it was.

Comment: OK, thanks for the writeup. Would it be advisable for me to edit the answers and put in whether they are talking about C or C++ ? (It can be discerned from the numbering in the standard reference).  I really do think two different questions is appropriate though, as it is a language-lawyer type question, and the standard text is substationally different in each.

Comment: @MattMcNabb That sounds reasonable, if it's not immediately obvious. I looked at doing the same, but (and it could be that it's just me), they all seem pretty ... self-explanatory. Some of the standards references are a little wordy but, well, that's sort of expected (be it as it is). I'd say sure, though - go for it if you think you can make it even better.